# How to convert html <table> to Handsontable which table has html input fields also

Tags: handsontable

I want to show a dynamic table which has records coming from a custom search.

Now I want to make the table row as an inline editable row.

I also need pagination with the table since I have 30 to 40 table columns which I need to display on the same table (scroll for columns).

I used Handsontable to achieve this as seen below, however, the image is not coming as I have entered in the table cell.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Scroll - Handsontable</title>

  <script data-jsfiddle="common" src="handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <link data-jsfiddle="common" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="handsontable.full.css">
</head>
<body>
      <div id="example1" style="width: 700px; height: 400px; overflow: auto">
       <table id="example" class="row-border hover order-column" cellspacing="0" style="Display: none;" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><img src="edit.jpg" height="20" width="20"/></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="edit.jpg" height="20" width="20"/></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="edit.jpg" height="20" width="20"/></td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
      <script data-jsfiddle="example1">
        var data=$('#example tr').map(function(tr){
        return [$(this).children().map(function(td){return $(this).text()}).get()]
        }).get()

        var
          example = document.getElementById('example1'),
          maximize = document.querySelector('.maximize'),
          maxed = false,
          resizeTimeout,
          availableWidth,
          availableHeight,
          hot1;

        hot1 = new Handsontable(example,{
          data: data,
//          colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80], //can also be a number or a function
          rowHeaders: false,
          colHeaders: false,
          fixedColumnsLeft: 2,
          fixedRowsTop: 1,
          minSpareRows: 1,
          contextMenu: true
        });

        function calculateSize() {
          var offset;

          if (maxed) {
            offset = Handsontable.Dom.offset(example);
            availableWidth = Handsontable.Dom.innerWidth(document.body) - offset.left + window.scrollX;
            availableHeight = Handsontable.Dom.innerHeight(document.body) - offset.top + window.scrollY;

            example.style.width = availableWidth + 'px';
            example.style.height = availableHeight + 'px';
          }
        }
      </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your definition of the Handsontable is correct. Are you pasting that HTML after it's rendered or is that what Handsontable is creating for you? I'm not sure if you knew or not but you don't need to define the table in the HTML for this to work. As a matter of fact you should NOT be defining it.

If this was just the rendered code, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "I have used Handsontable for achieve this as below. but image not coming as i have entered in table cell."? What parts are wrong and what do you need changed?

Comment: Hi when i am trying to add image in table like '<td><img src="edit.jpg" height="15" width="15" style="text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;"/></td>' and then convert it into handsontable data 'var data=$('#example tr').map(function(tr){
  return [$(this).children().map(function(td){return $(this).html()}).get()]
  }).get();' then it will put image as a <img...></img> code instead of image itself on UI.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What is the question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cells : function (row, col, prop) { return { renderer: 'html' }; }
```

as an option in your hot1 definition.